# How promise is resolved by function call?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I found this snippet for promise which I can use in Promise.race() to prevent waiting long asynchronous operations if some my code in parallel will be finished faster.

```
let stopCallback = null;
const stopPromise = new Promise(x => stopCallback = x);

await stopPromise; // promise pending until stopCallback() will be executed somewhere
```

But I can't fully understand how this Promise exactly works.

Please, can someone explain to me how this promise resolves or give any link to where such usecase is described in detail?

Comment: x is `resolve` callback, you are setting it to a global variable `stopCallback `. so until you don't call the `resolve` i.e. `stopCallback ` callback this promise won't resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it is clearer if you call `x` another name :

```
let stopCallback = null;
const stopPromise = new Promise( resolve => stopCallback = resolve);
```

Indeed, whenever you call `stopCallback()`, it's equivalent to call `resolve()` and it resolves the Promise.

Answer (score 0):

Promise has 2 callback functions.
1)resolve and 2)reject

```
let stopCallback = null;
const stopPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    // call here resolve or reject ,by this promise exexution will be completed
    // resolve('data') or reject('data')
    });
(async () => {
  const resolvedOrRejectedData = await stopPromise;
})
```

if you don't resolve or reject promise, then it will be remain in pending state.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a Promise is *just a wrapper around callbacks*. It could (more or less) be written as:

```
 class Promise {
   _resolved = undefined;
   _handlers = [];

   constructor(callback) {
     callback(function resolve(value) {
       this._resolved = value;
       this._handlers.forEach(h => h(value));
     }, /*reject*/);
   }

   then(handler) {
     if(this._resolved) handler(this._resolved); 
     this._handlers.push(handler);
     // return new Promise(...);
   }
 }
```

So in other words: If you call `promise.then(callback)` then that `callback` will be stored inside the promise. Then when you call `resolve()` of the promise, it goes through all the callbacks stored and calls them.

Now `await stopPromise;` calls `.then(...)` on that promise, and passes an internal function into it, that when called resumes the execution of the current `async function`. Then it halts the execution of that function. Thus if you resolve your promise through the callback, all `.then(...)` callbacks get called, also the one registered in the async function, which then continues execution of the `async function`.

Comment: This simplification of promise behavior may mislead beginners who aren't aware that  the resolve function is overloaded on parameter type. Chiefly,  if the resolving value is a Promise object, then handlers are **not** called.

Comment: @traktor53 sure, thats the problem with simplifications of all kind.